# Django Forms - localize=True doesn't seem to be working

Tags: django, localization, django-forms

I'm trying to have forms accept decimals with a different decimal separator but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have `USE_L10N = True` in settings and `localize=True` in my form field but it only accepts periods on both machines I'm testing (should accept commas in my secondary machine)

Is there something I am missing?

I am using Windows and I haven't done anything in regards to generating translation files/locale folders.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with this form:

```
class InvoiceItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price = forms.CharField(max_length=10, min_length=1, localize=True)
    quantity = forms.CharField(max_length=10, min_length=1, localize=True)
```

Also on settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

And check the "Accept-Language" that your browser is sending to the server.
Mine is "en-us,en;q=0.8,es-es;q=0.5,es;q=0.3" and shows format in "en".